# Show Loader when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to obtain a loader when a button is clicked (for a signup) without create another page (only to show the loader).
How can I do??

This is my code and what I tried (but it doesn't appears)

```
class Signup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     //code about signup
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  showLoader = () =>{
    this.setState({ isLoading: true})
    this.registrazione()
  }
  registrazione() {
    //code about signup

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.container}>
        //code about signup
          <View style={style.footer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
              onPress={() => this.showLoader()}
            >
              <Text style={[style.buttonTesto]}>Signup</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.isLoading} size="large" color="#56cbbe" />
          </View>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Working demo here https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/loader-on-click

Comment: @ThakurKarthik Thank you for the answer, the problem is that I should launch also this.registrazione() (that there isn't in the code that you post)

Comment: @ThakurKarthik I have tried to add but the loader isn't showen :(

Comment: Try to log the isLoading variable and check if the registrazione method is not changing it till the end of the its body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have one closing View tag that is not needed.
Assuming that's just mistake in question, you could do it with JS ternary operator. Like this:

```
<View style={style.container}>
        //code about signup
          <View style={style.footer}>
            {(!this.state.isLoading) ? <TouchableOpacity
              style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
              onPress={() => this.showLoader()}
            >
              <Text style={[style.buttonTesto]}>Signup</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> : <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.isLoading} size="large" color="#56cbbe" />}
          </View>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
</View>
```

You can learn more about ternary operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

This should replace your button with loading animation.

Don't hesitate to ask any more questions if you have any! I'm glad to help!